# multidimensional search not showing all results

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array search

my array looks like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [location] => 3
            [location_fees] => 3
            [gross_percentage] => 25
            [transaction_percentage] => 0
            [user_name] => admin
            [user_id] => 1
            [gross] => yes
            [transaction] => no
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [location] => 5
            [location_fees] => 5
            [gross_percentage] => 0
            [transaction_percentage] => 24
            [user_name] => admin
            [user_id] => 1
            [gross] => no
            [transaction] => yes
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [location] => 2
            [location_fees] => 5
            [gross_percentage] => 10
            [transaction_percentage] => 0
            [user_name] => admin
            [user_id] => 1
            [gross] => yes
            [transaction] => no
        )

)
```

i use the following php, i know it can probably be done cleaner or a lot less code so if you have any ideas how to get the same result i am def all about learning and i am all ears!

so here is the PHP i use:

```
    $key = false;
    $search = ['gross' => 'yes'];
    foreach ($results as $k => $v) {
    if ($v['gross'] == $search['gross'] ) {

        $key = $k;

        $location_fees = array_search('yes', array_column($results, 'gross','location_fees'));
        echo  "The location fees: ". $location_fees ." % <br><br>";
     
        $gross_percentage = array_search('yes', array_column($results, 'gross', 'gross_percentage'));
        echo "The gross_percentage is: ".$gross_percentage ."% <br><br>";

    }  else  {

        $tran_perc = array_search('yes', array_column($results, 'transaction', 'transaction_percentage'));
        echo "The locations percentage is: ".$tran_perc ." % <br>";

        $the_loc = array_search('yes', array_column($results, 'transaction', 'location'));
        echo "The location is: ".$the_loc ."  <br>";

        $location_fees = array_search('no', array_column($results, 'gross','location_fees'));
        echo  "The location fees: ". $location_fees ." % <br><br>";

    }
    }
```

and my results on the page look like this:

```
    key 0
    The location fees: 3 %
    The gross_percentage is: 25%

    key 1
    The locations percentage is: 24 %
    The location is: 5
    The location fees: %

    key 2
    The location fees: 8 %
    The gross_percentage is: 25%
```

it refuses to show the  locations fee from  key #1

NOW the strange parts is,  if i change the  location fees to say 3, it then shows up.  but it will not with the number "5"  which is also the location #

Is there a reason this is a conflict with JUST that number  "5"?  Notice Key "0"   has location of "3" and location fees  of "3" and it does not cause any issues.

I have been stuck on this for hours,  it will work for keys # 0 and #2  without any issues.   Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are running into this issue is your call to `array_column`:

```
array_column($results, 'gross','location_fees')
```

this causes the `gross` values from `$results` to be re-indexed by the `location_fees` values, which for your data would result in something like

```
[3 => 'yes', 5 => 'no', 5 => 'yes']
```

As you can see, you have two `5` numeric keys, which is not valid, so the second one overwrites the first and you end up with

```
[3 => 'yes', 5 => 'yes']
```

and your `array_search` for `no` fails, hence you get no results. You will have this problem everywhere you get a replicated value.

I'm not sure why you are taking this approach anyway. It seems you have the numbers you want in `$v` anyway:

```
$search = ['gross' => 'yes'];
foreach ($results as $k => $v) {
    echo "key $k<br>" . PHP_EOL;
    if ($v['gross'] == $search['gross'] ) {
        $location_fees = $v['location_fees'];
        echo  "The location fees: ". $location_fees ." % <br><br>" . PHP_EOL;
     
        $gross_percentage = $v['gross_percentage'];
        echo "The gross_percentage is: ".$gross_percentage ."% <br><br>" . PHP_EOL;

    }  else  {

        $tran_perc = $v['transaction_percentage'];
        echo "The locations percentage is: ".$tran_perc ." % <br>" . PHP_EOL;

        $the_loc = $v['location'];
        echo "The location is: ".$the_loc ."  <br>" . PHP_EOL;

        $location_fees = $v['location_fees'];
        echo  "The location fees: ". $location_fees ." % <br><br>" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
key 0<br>
The location fees: 3 % <br><br>
The gross_percentage is: 25% <br><br>
key 1<br>
The locations percentage is: 24 % <br>
The location is: 5  <br>
The location fees: 5 % <br><br>
key 2<br>
The location fees: 5 % <br><br>
The gross_percentage is: 10% <br><br>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/gTBf7)

Comment: I went this route after scouring this site for help on a solution of another problem.   I never thought of it being in the variable $v.   Thank you for the detailed response

Comment: can i ask you another question @nick ?   ```    Thanks ```